# is android emulator firewall safe from firewall(e.g all internet logs will go in encrypted form)?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am confused with this thing, is emulator safe from pc network's firewall like no one knows what we surf? I want to know on this, does anybody know about it?

Comment: Do you mean "safe", as nobody can see where the request is going to?

Comment: yes like that, i know this is odd question but want to know whether exactly the any web request can be traced? as i dont want to know go through proxy to access any banned sites, but whether the request is encrypted by default?

Comment: @steveoh  :  whether the request is encrypted even if we do regular requests by default?

Comment: stick with the answer written by zrgiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests made by the emulator are just like requests made by any other app. If you access a HTTPS website on your emulator, the data will be transmitted encrypted, just as it would be if you used your computer's browser.